# Recycler to Viewpager shared element transition: flash coming only on first click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm doing recyclerview to viewpager fragment to fragment shared element transition my problem is flash is occurring only when viewpager first time launch if i click same itemor any other item in viewpager flash didnt occur it work perfectly, what could be reasons? here is my code:

```
on click of recyclerview item:

holder.iv.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");

            ImagePagerFragment productDetailFragment = new ImagePagerFragment();

                getActive.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        .addSharedElement(holder.iv, holder.iv.getTransitionName())
                        .replace(R.id.fragment, productDetailFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

In ImagePagerFragment that has viewpager:

```
 prepareSharedElementTransition();
postponeEnterTransition();
```

prepareSharedElementTransition():

```
 Transition transition =
    TransitionInflater.from(getContext())
        .inflateTransition(R.transition.image_shared_element_transition);
setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
setEnterSharedElementCallback(
    new SharedElementCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
        Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter()
            .instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        View view = currentFragment.getView();
        if (view == null) {
          return;
        }
        sharedElements.put(names.get(0), view.findViewById(R.id.image1));
      }
    });
```

ImagePagerAdapter is FragmentStatePagerAdapter returning ImageFragment, In ImageFragment:

```
 Picasso.with(getActivity())
          .load(url)
          .into(ivZoom, new Callback() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess() {

                  ivZoom.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");
                  getParentFragment().startPostponedEnterTransition();

              }

              @Override
              public void onError() {
                  ivZoom.setTransitionName(MainActivity.position + "ZoomImage");
                  getParentFragment().startPostponedEnterTransition();
              }
          });
```

Comment: I think you should set transition in `ImageFragment`s `onViewCreated` and not in Picasso callback.

Comment: no difference....

Comment: @LieForBananas happened because of picasso delay loading, solved

Comment: Great news :) happy you solved the problem

Comment: Indeed :) but struggling with new problem, exit transitions is not working :(

Comment: The exit trainsition should be automatic, I had the same problems but I forgot what I did

Comment: yes it should be automatic, I have button on image on clicking on it I have to exit fragment with shared element transition, on button click I', poping back stack to go to recyclerview fragment

Comment: And when you press back button the exit transition works?

Comment: No, on back pressed also i have pop back stack

Comment: Then I'm not sure, maybe you have to manage the return transition manually

Comment: in prepareSharedElementTransition(); i have setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
    setSharedElementReturnTransition(new Slide()); (slide just for experiment)

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't implemented the return transition. I set up the enter transition and the return was taken care of

Comment: Yes it happend automatically when i was doing with activity, i called finishActivityAdterTransition() and it worked perfect

Comment: Should be the same here, I have the same case, try to remove any return transitions so it's handled automatically, other than that I don't really know :)